# JQuery get attributes of radio input inside a group

Tags: php, jquery, radio-group

Here is my PHP code to generate dynamic form inputs

```
echo '<div class="radio" id="'.$questionID.'">';
foreach ($options as $key => $opt_value) { 
$option_text = $opt_value->option_text;
$question_id = $opt_value->question_id;
$is_correct = $opt_value->is_correct;
$option_id = $opt_value->id;
 echo '<label>
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="optionCheck'.$questionID.'" id="'.$option_id.'" value="'.$option_id.'" data-id="'.$option_id.'" data-title="optionCheck'.$questionID.'"><p>
'.$option_text.'</p>
</label>';  
}
echo '</div>';
```

I am generating radio buttons inside div. Each div for a question and the radio inputs are its variable options.

JQuery to get data for each question:

```
function fetchAttempt(){
     var jsonArr = [];
     $('.radio').each(function() {
    var selected_option =  -1;      
    var is_skipped = 1;
    var correct_option = 0;
    var quesId = $(this).attr('id');
     var quesOptns = "optionCheck"+quesId;
    $('.'+questOptns).each(function() {
        if(($(this).val()) == 1){
            correct_option = $(this).attr("id");
        }else{
            correct_option = -1;
        }
         });
jsonArr.push({
            correct_option: correct_option,
            is_skipped: is_skipped,
            correct_option: is_right,
            selected_option: selected_option,
            temp_id: temp_id,
            question_id: quesId
        });
    });
    return JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
}
```

I struggled for more than 5 hours ... still unable to get the access the checked radio value inside a group.

I tried all possible ways... to get the value of checked radio inside a div by a name ... but it never worked.

Comment: when you are calling `fetchAttempt` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have your `$options` variable, so I created my own questions
>   form to simulate your situation.

To select a `radio button` we have only to use this jQuery `$("input[type=radio]:checked")` then we must check everyone of these checked radio buttons using the function [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Here is a full example of what you should do:

```js
$("#submit").on("click",function(){

$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio" id="form1">
<label>Question 1
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="name1" id="'id1" value="value1" data-id="option1" data-title="question1"></label><br>

<label>Question 2
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="name2" id="'id2" value="value2" data-id="option2" data-title="question2"></label><br>

<label>Question 3
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="name3" id="'id3" value="value3" data-id="option3" data-title="question3"></label><br>

<label>Question 4
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="name4" id="'id4" value="value4" data-id="option4" data-title="question4"></label><br>

<label>Question 5
<input type="radio" class="optionChecked" name="name5" id="'id5" value="value5" data-id="option5" data-title="question5"></label><br>

<button type="button" id="submit"> Submit</button>
</div>
```